# How to replace type bool in pandas dataframe with strings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, types

I have a dataframe with values:

```
  Name      Enrolled
JarJar          TRUE
  Boba         FALSE
```

I want to replace instances of TRUE/FALSE (regardless of case) with TRUE_/FALSE_.

I tried using this code snippet here:

```
df_to_add = df_to_add.replace('(?i)true', 'TRUE_', regex=True)
df_to_add = df_to_add.replace('(?i)false', 'FALSE_', regex=True)
```

but nothing happens since the TRUE/FALSE values in the dataframe are currently numpy.bool. How can I work around this?

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Name' : ['JarJar', 'Boba', 'Foo', 'bar', 'foobar', 'foobaaz'], 'Enrolled' : ['TRUE', 'FALSE', 'true', 'false', 'True', 'False']})    
df = df.replace({r"TRUE(?i)": "_TRUE", r"False(?i)": "_FALSE"}, regex=True)

print(df)
```

Output :

```
      Name Enrolled
0   JarJar    _TRUE
1     Boba   _FALSE
2      Foo    _TRUE
3      bar   _FALSE
4   foobar    _TRUE
5  foobaaz   _FALSE
```

Comment: this does not work as the booleans in my dataframe are of type bool so it's not a simple str replacement

Comment: Well you tell us "regardless of the case" which basically means it's a string

Comment: sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

df_to_add.replace({True: 'TRUE_', False: 'FALSE_'}, inplace=True)